# Active Record: Implicit value for part of multi column belongs_to key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, composite-primary-key

We have multiple lists of shops from different data sources that have to be matched.

The shops have a composite primary key [source, id]. The matching creates a separate entry in the shops table with source=0 and extracts values (name, url, ...) that can differ a bit from source to source.

Now I could add another two columns meta_shop_source and meta_shop_id to shops and a belongs_to :meta_shop, class_name "Shop", foreign_key: [:meta_shop_source, :meta_shop_id] to the Shop model. I am using the composite_primary_keys gem.

However, as meta_shop_source is always 0, it would seem like a waste of space. The same process will later on be used for products and there are millions of rows, so optimization will be needed.

So I am looking for something like belongs_to :meta_shop, class_name "Shop", foreign_key: [0, :meta_shop_id] or a method that I can override so that I don't need the meta_shop_source column in my database.

Answer (score 0):

The one alternative is to define the value in the model so that you can directly access it from the controller directly.

But yes for undefined columns in tables, `attr_accessor` can be used as you don't want to store in the database directly and that will only exist for the life of the object.

```
attr_accessor :source
```

If the `meta_shop_source` will always be 0, then there is no need to create a column with this field in the table.

Just use a foreign primary key, `meta_shop_id`.

Similarly, the primary key for the Shop should be `id`.

Having so, you will never have to worry about the source as it will be 0 always.

You can define the value in the model so that you can directly access it.

UPDATE:

As far as optimization is concerned then do it at migration level by adding indexes with:
`add_index` wherever necessary. Eliminating one column just because of one source having 0 is not a good idea and will not effect the performance. This may be possible if all of the sources also have values greater than 0.

Since you have a distinct “source” field, an index can be created. By creating an Index, you would be basically creating an internal register which gets saved in by the MySQL itself.

```
ALTER TABLE shop ADD INDEX (source);
```

Upon creation and setting of the Index, later whenever you wish to fetch some information pertaining to the individual who has been assigned the source 5, the service would straight-way go to it by using the index, hence generate a result at a much faster pace than the earlier query.

Comment: shops.source is always 0 for meta shops, but there are also entries for other sources in the same table with source > 0. If I just set the foreign_key to meta_shop_id, it will give me a matching record with the right shops.id, but a random shops.source. I do have to have a composite primary key, but one component (the source) would be fixed. Should I provide a more concise problem definition?

Comment: So you can have source > 0, than it means you have to preserve the source entries in database. It is then irrelevant to eliminate just for shops source because this is not the only source you have. The others can have more than 0. But offcourse you can use indexing for optimization.